# I need the Jersey Multipart Client and server code to Upload more than one file.?

Tags: jersey, multipartform-data

I need the Jersey Multipart Client to Upload more than one file.

I am able to upload a Single file but how can i upload more than one file.

In the client i set the two filedatabody parts.

```
final FileDataBodyPart filePart = new FileDataBodyPart("file", new File("path"));

FormDataMultiPart formDataMultiPart = new FormDataMultiPart();

FileDataBodyPart filePart2 = new FileDataBodyPart("file", new File("path2"));
final FormDataMultiPart multipart =
    (FormDataMultiPart) formDataMultiPart.field("foo", "bar").bodyPart(filePart).bodyPart(filePart2);
```

How to write the server side code.

Answer (score 1):

The `"file"` you're using here `new FileDataBodyPart("file", new File("path2"));` is the *name* of the body part. If you are going to name them the same (which *is* allowed), then use a `List` for your parameter type

```
public Response upload(@FormDataParam("file") List<InputSream> files)
```

Otherwise if you want to change the name of one of the parts, then just add another `@FormDataParam` parameter using that part's name

```
public Response upload(@FormDataParam("file1") InputStream file1,
                       @FormDataParam("file2") InputStream file2)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  I need the first option with list. Also there is another parameter like @FormDataParam("file") final FormDataContentDisposition fileMetaData. How to configure this incase of list. ie(FormDataContentDisposition  as list)